# Chartjs Counting Elements in a Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

I am trying to get the count of elements in an object. However, my chart is empty despite the fact that i can see my data when i log it. How am I supposed to pass the data to the dataset or should i do a count first?

My code

```
var url = "{{url('myurl') }}";
    var Clinics = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(url, function(response) {
           console.log(response)

            response.forEach(function(element) {
                Clinics = element.clinic

            });
            
           var Labels =  ["Paediatric", "Gynaecology Outpatient Clinic", "Physiotherapy Clinic", "Nutrition Clinic", "Dental Clinic", "Optical Clinic", "Well Baby Clinic", "Dermatology Clinic", "Surgical Outpatient Clinic", "Orthopaedic Clinic", "Medical Outpatient Physician", "Comprehensive Care Clinics", "Oncology", "Gastroenterology Clinic", ]
        
            var ctx = document.getElementById("clinicChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: Labels,    
                        datasets: [{
                            fillColor: "#79D1CF",
                            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",
                            label: 'Patient Visits',
                            data: Clinics,
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: can you add a console.log after response.forEach to see your variable has data?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `Clinics` variable.

```js
response.forEach((element) => {
  Clinics.push(element.clinic);
});
```

Comment: I think he set the data is an array, so it makes sense he assigned it directly

Comment: He is looping over the `response` as a forEach. The last `element.clinic` is being assigned to `Clinics`

Comment: you are right, and because it is not an array anymore, it seems Chartjs can't display it

Comment: @ChrisG When i do a console.log i see an array of all the clinics, but my chart is still empty

Comment: @shiro Are you certain that your data is an array of numbers?  Without seeing a sample set of your data, it is difficult to determine the problem.

Comment: I converted it to an array of numbers and it worked. Thanks